# Designing in C++ using object-oriented principles

Tags: c++, oop

I am preparing for an interview and doing the tasks from the book "Cracking the Coding Interview". I know that there are answers to these tasks, but unfortunately in object-oriented design they are very blurred and I do not know if I do them right or wrong. Please, take a look at my solution and tell me what can be done better in this particular answer. And Please, rate my solution. In particular, I'm interested in what recruiters pay attention to such questions.

Question:
Design a musical jukebox using object-oriented principles.

My answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class ListToPlay {
  std::queue<const Song&> queue_to_play_;
  const Speaker& speaker;
public:
  void Play();
  void AddSong(const Song& song);
  void RemoveSong(int index);
  void Clean();
  const std::queue<const Song&>& getQueueToPlay() const;
};

class Song {
  std::ostream data_;
  std::string name_;
public:
  const std::ostream getData() const;
  const std::string getName() const;
  void setData(std::ostream data);
  void setName(std::string name);
};

class CD {
  std::vector<Song> sangs_;
  std::string name_;
  std::string author_;
public:
  const std::vector<Song>& getSongs() const;
  const std::string& getName() const;
  const std::string& getAuthor() const;
  void addSong(Song song);
  void setName(std::string name);
  void setAuthor(std::string author);
};

class Grafics {
  const ListToPlay& list_to_play_;
  const std::vector<CD>& cd_vector_;
public:
  void setCDVector(const std::vector<CD>& cd_vector_);
  void setListToPlay(const ListToPlay& list_to_play);
  void ClickedPlay();
  void ClickedStop();
  void ClickedClean();
  void ClickedAddToPlayList(int index);
  void ClickedSelectCD();
};

class Speaker {
public:
  void PlaySound(Song song);
};

class Jukebox {
public:
  Grafics grafics_;
  Speaker speaker_;
  std::vector<CD> cd_vector_;
  std::vector<ListToPlay> list_to_play_;

  Jukebox(Grafics grafics, Speaker speaker, std::vector<CD> cd_vector)
    : grafics_(grafics), speaker_(speaker), cd_vector_(cd_vector) { ; }
};

int main()
{
  ;
}
```

I can describe how I came up with it, but I don't know if the code shouldn't defend itself. If you need an additional description, write and I will write it.

I moved this question from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, because they said: this is designing not coding".

Comment: Well your code doesn't compile. Nothing to do with OO design, but if it doesn't compile then the design is irrelevant.

Comment: Except in rare cases don't store references in classes, so ListToPlay is wrong and `std::queue<const Song&>` simply won't compile.

Comment: `Song` doesn't compile because streams are not copyable objects. In any case I would question storing a stream in a class called `Song`, surely the Song is the content of the stream. Possibly you would store the data required to create a stream in the Song class, but not the stream itself.

Comment: You don't "design in C++ using object-oriented principles". OO design as an approach is mostly independent of programming language, and represents a system as a set of interacting objects and types (categories) of objects, their static (e.g. state) and dynamic (time-based) properties, relationships (e.g. is-a, association, aggregation, ....), and set of operations that allow objects to share information and interact. The design is then mapped to constructs of a chosen programming language, like C++, with possibly some adjustments to deal with capabilities or limitations of the language.

Comment: You have some getters which are getting references to objects stored in vectors. Objects in vectors may change position and invalidate pointers and refs to them! So it is dangerous to deal with refs to objects stored in vectors!

Comment: First, thanks, this answers helped me. To @john, you have right, this: 'std::queue<const Song&>' won't compile. You said: **Except in rare cases don't store references in classes**, but I looked at [link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments) and they suggest using references in const value. Maybe only in function. Can you clarify me this?

Comment: @Klaus, only in ctor Jukebox I modify this vectors, so during running it will not change. Also, song will contain most data of the program, so I don't want to copy these songs. In this situation I shouldn't use references, and should I copy songs?

Comment: General question: What recruters want to check in such question, and how to answer on such question? P.S. While answering, you have only Word or same IDE, you don't have something to drawing UML.

Comment: @wojtek That link refers to function arguments, I was talking about class members like `ListToPlay::speaker` for instance. If your object holds a reference to another object, then you create a dependency between the two objects, your object is only valid as long as the other object continues to exist. That's a hard relationship to manage and in most cases unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, but Dependency Injection? From one hand I shouldn't do this, from other I should. Please explain me this too.